# UWP app MainWindow not displaying the second button on the left

Tags: uwp, windows-10, uwp-xaml

I've tried various variations but when I run the app the second button of the `MainWindow` does not show. It seems I'm not quite understanding the design patterns of the app. **Question**: what changes should I make to the `XAML` here to have second button (titled Test2) displayed when app runs?

**Remark**: It's a `Windows 10` laptop. I'm using `VS2019`.

**XAML**

```
<Page
    x:Class="UWPTest.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:UWPTest"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

    <Grid>
        <Button x:Name="btnTest" Content="Test" Margin="69,1,0,0" Click="BtnTest_Click" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <Button x:Name="btnGetSelContSrcView" Content="Test2" Margin="69,47,0,921" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Click="BtnGetSelContSrcView_Click"/>
        <WebView x:Name="wvTest" Margin="130,38,0,10" DOMContentLoaded="WvTest_DOMContentLoaded"/>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

**Snaphot of Design View**

[image]

**Snaphot Main Window after app runs** [FULL Screen mode om 17" monitor]

Note that the second button is not displayed.

[image]

**Snaphot Main Window after first button is clicked** [FULL Screen mode om 17" monitor]

**Note** that the first button click event displays the html on right side (as expected) but the second button is not displayed here either.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use StackPanel for correct alignment and Grid ColumnDefinitions or Grid RowDefinitions

**Example:**

```
<Grid Loaded="Page_Loaded">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="32"/>
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Grid Grid.Row="0">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Button Content="Pre page" />
            <Button Content="Next page" />
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
    <Grid Grid.Row="1">
        <WebView Source="https://google.com" />
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ql1sf.png)

**Links:**

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/layout/layout-panels

Comment: Welcome to `Stack Overflow`. For me the [Grid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/layout/layout-panels#grid) section of the link you provided was very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

**Cause:** The margin "Margin="69,47,0,921"" you used in the second button means 47 distance from the top of the screen and 921 distance from the bottom of the screen.When you run the app,once the screen height less than 968,then the second button won't display,because it's height is equal to 0.So when you maximize the screen,the second button will display.

**Solution:** You can try the following code to set the second button.

```
<Button x:Name="btnTest" Content="Test" Margin="69,1,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
<Button x:Name="btnGetSelContSrcView" Content="Test2" Margin="69,47,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
```